# Moving values in Array to the left/right to k positions?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of n values. I have a value p which can be 1 or -1. I have to move the positions in the Array k positions to the left if p = 1 or to the right if p = -1.

1 ≤ N ≤ 1.000.000
0 ≤ K ≤ 1.000.000

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int n, p, k;
   int v[1000002];
   cin >> n >> k >> p;

   for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
       cin >> v[i];
   }

   if( p == 1) {
       for ( int i = k + 1; i <= n ; i++ ) {
           cout << v[i] << " ";
       }
       for ( int i = 1; i <= k; i++ ) {
           cout << v[i] << " ";
       }
   }
   else {
       for ( int i = n - k + 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
           cout << v[i] << " ";
       }
       for ( int i = 1; i <= n - k; i++ ) {
           cout << v[i] << " ";
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is I use an online tester to do tests on it to see if it applies to all possible cases, but this solution passes all but 3 tests. The results are correct, but it says that I have surpassed the time limit for the respective test. I cannot comprehend how because I only use essential code like reading and printing the array.

Comment: You should try it with fast IO methods.

Comment: Unelated: Do you know about [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)? Would simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: What you have done is not moving/rotating array elements but printing them in a specific order based on input value `p`. Also, instead of taking such a huge static array `int v[1000002]` better to go for a container.

Comment: Well I figured if I just print them in another order I can skip the moving part to win some time. Apparently it is not fast enough

Comment: Your algorithm is indeed fast enough. It's just O(n) for the reading and the printing. But it looks like your IO is too slow. Every cin and cout is a system call. For the output, you could gather it all in one buffer, and print it all at once. I'm not sure how to get the input in one buffer.

Comment: This is cheating. Imagine if this was a method or function call with `void` return type. You have to edit the array in place. Also, I don't prefer OJ platforms which expect you to use fast IO because they are not really concentrating on the algorithm but rather on other aspects. If that is so important to them, they could provide you with a boilerplate or in some form of some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help resolve your timeouts, but I can see the following to reduce your calls a tiny bit:

1. After you read in n, p and k, calculate your offset.
2. Create a vector that is offset in size.
3. Read into vector until it's full.
4. Pipe all input directly to stdout.
5. Write out of the vector to stdout.

This process will reduce the readin->writeout to a single step for (n - offset elements, where offset = k or n - k depending on p).

If this still fails, you can build a stringstream and write to stringstream, and flush to cout once in a while (i.e. every 8 k or so) to reduce calls to your io channel (cout).

Sample code:

```
   int n, p, k;
   cin >> n >> k >> p;
   int offset = p == 1 ? k : n - k;
   std::vector tmp(offset);
   std::stringstream sout;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < offset; i++)
   {
      cin >> tmp[i];
   }

   for (size_t i = offset; i < n; i++)
   {
      cin >> sout << ' ';
      if (sout.size() > _BUFFER_MAX)
      {
         cout << sout.str();
         std::stringstream().swap(sout);
      }
   }

   cout << sout.str();
   std::stringstream().swap(sout);

   for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
   {
      sout << tmp[i] << ' ';
      if (sout.size() > _BUFFER_MAX)
      {
         cout << sout.str();
         std::stringstream().swap(sout);
      }
   }

   cout << sout.str();
```

Comment: This is going to be very slow in many cases without `cin.tie(NULL)`

Comment: Do you want to explain what you mean?  cin will be the same as OP's, and cout will be faster due to less calls using the 8k buffer "sout".

Comment: By default, every time you read from `cin`, it flushes pending output in `cout` all the way to the OS.  That defeats buffering in `cout` and `stdout`, making a lot of slow low-level IO operations when you interleave reading with writing.

Comment: What are you talking about?  The sout buffer is a string stream and only goes to cout in 8k blocks, so even with the pending cout flushes, it's only occurring occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the way you're trying to "cheat".  There will be many times in your programming career when the best plan is to provide what the customer asks for, completely ignoring the way they think you should provide it.

That enormous array at the beginning is awful, though -- you should use a std::vector with n elements, not 10000002.

I'm surprised that you are running out of time, since all the time is in I/O, and you are making the "obvious" I/O calls that will be similar to what everyone else is doing... but there are a lot of details you don't know about the test environment.

Try putting this at he start of `main`:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

By default, every time you write to `cout`, the data is pushed into the `stdout` C stream.   It's possible that the test environment is set up in a way the makes this slow.

If you turn off the syncing, you can use `cout`'s internal bufferring, which will make all those little writes a lot faster in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. if k is very large you can simply take it to the mod n (k%n)
2. you can perform placements in O(n) by calculating the final index of each element after rotation using the formulas:
   (i + k) % n for right rotation and (i - k) % n for left rotation.

- note: you should add an extra 'n' to handle negative modulo.

here's the code:

```cpp
int v[1000001];
int main() {

    int n, p, k; 
    cin >> n >> k >> p;
    
    k %= n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        if (p == -1) //right
            cin >> v[(i + k) % n];
        
        else if (p == 1) //left
            cin >> v[(i - k + n) % n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the problem in my code.

Apparently the problem was that the number of positions to move could be bigger than the actual number of values. This led to some very long for's.

I feel pretty stupid , but I have learned many new things through your answers. Thank you very much!